# Codeigniter get mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, instagram-api

Can someone please guide me how I can fetch mysql row's value for "pk" to the $response variable to be able to allow the script to unfollow users automatically. I have already tried the script and it does unfollow when an pk id is provided but I want to automatically fetch it from mysql to be able to run it. Thank you for any help provided.

These are the methods I tried with no success:

```
$this->db->select('pk');
$this->model->from(INSTAGRAM_FOLLOW_TB);
$this->db->where("id = '11'");
$query1 = $this->db->get();
$result =  $query1->result();
```

Main ID that only unfollow this ID- created by Mushfik Media,

```
$response = $i->unfollow($result);
```

I have also tried

```
$accounts = $this->model->fetch("*", INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNT_TB, "id = '11'");

$response = $i->unfollow($accounts->pk);
```

But didn't work. $NEED MYSQL DATA VALUE is where the value is supposed to be echoed but doesn't

```
case 'unfollow':
    try {
        $result = $i->getSelfUsersFollowing();

        if(!empty($result) && $result->status == "ok" && !empty($result->users)){

            $response = $i->unfollow($NEED MYSQL DATA VALUE); 
            $response = $response->status;
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->model('Schedule_model', 'schedule_model');
            $lang = $CI->db->insert(INSTAGRAM_FOLLOW_TB, array(
                    "pk" => $row->pk,
                    "name" => $row->username,
                    "type"         => $data->schedule_type,
                    "uid"          => $data->uid,
                    "account_id"   => $data->account,
                    "account_name" => $data->name,
                            "created"      => NOW
                    ));
        }

    } catch (Exception $e){

        $response = $e->getMessage();
    }

break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this to get your pk:

```
$query1 = $this->db->select('pk')
    ->from(INSTAGRAM_FOLLOW_TB)
    ->where('id', 11)
    ->get();

if( $query1->num_rows() == 1 ){
    $row =  $query1->row(); 
    $response = $i->unfollow( $row->pk );
}
```

Regarding your information that you are trying to use $this when not in object context, because you are in a helper, you need to get the CI super object. So, if you were trying to use $this->db, you would do this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
// Now you can use $CI->db
// and anything you would normally
// access via $this in a controller
// or model
```

OK, finally to show an example of how to order or limit a query:

```
$query1 = $this->db->select('pk')
    ->from(INSTAGRAM_FOLLOW_TB)
    ->where('id', 11)
    ->order_by('your_timestamp_field', 'ASC') // This would order by timestamp in ascending order
    ->limit(1) // This would limit to a single row
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't actually bring the pk value

Comment: Since that  is true, more information would be needed. You can check the actual SQL query meets your needs by viewing it with:

$this->db->last_query();

My query has a fixed id of 11, which you probably need to alter.

Comment: This is the error shows up on error_log: [13-Aug-2017 22:54:07 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /home/testt/public_html/instagram_helper.php on line 811

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to access db inside a helper. Also, why is your helper not inside /application/helpers?

Comment: Thank You! Its solved. Really appreciate your time and effort

Comment: $CI =& get_instance();
                             $INSTAGRAM = $CI->model->get("*", INSTAGRAM_FOLLOW_TB, "id = '6'");
Sorry, how can I ask mysql only for first row pk id to be given. Rows also have timestamp, which can also be used to ascend to get only first row. I tried but not working: $row = $query->INSTAGRAM();  if (isset($row))
{
 $response = $i->unfollow($row->pk);
}

Comment: In CodeIgniter when using the database libraries, you can use limit() and order_by(). You will want to read about those in the user guide, and implement them in your query.

Comment: Can you please just give me example with my code. That will be the end then. Thank You

Comment: See the revised answer